# Match a string against a set of keywords associated with a key

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of text files (song lyrics) to return based on the user input:

```
song_1.txt
song_2.txt
...
song_n.txt
```

I'm not happy with the idea of listing all of them at once for the user to choose from, so my initial thought was to create a simple function that takes user input as an argument, performs a search against a list of pre-defined keywords per song and returns the "best matching song" as a response.

I'm fairly new to python and programming in general and best thing I could think of so far is something like that:

```py
keywords = {'song_1': ['hate', 'bad'], 'song_2': ['love', 'good']}

def find_song_by_keyword(user_input):
    for song, keyword in keywords.items():
        if user_input in keyword:
            return song + '.txt'


result = find_song_by_keyword('love')
print(result)
```

```
song_2.txt
```

Then I'm going to read a song from file and return it to the user, but my question is:

- What's the best way to match a string to keywords considering the fact I need to trace back the "key"? I have a feeling there's a better solution to match something to keywords instead of using for loop + dictionary with list as a value. Just looking for some directions on that matter in general (I'd appreciate a link to something related to "search" in general, maybe something deeper than that).

Comment: Invert the dictionary, and have keywords map to songs. `{'hate': 'song_1', 'bad': 'song_1', 'love': 'song_2', 'good': 'song_2'}`. Then you can just get `keywords.get(user_input)`

Comment: @Barmar - Aren't dup keys going to be a problem here?

Comment: The loop only finds one song per keyword, so duplicates are ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using a `for`-loop, especially since you exit when you find the first match and that appears to be what you need.

However, you could get the key like this as well:

```
result = next((song for song, words in keywords.items() if 'love' in words), None)
```

Or, if you don't want to repeat yourself and you need to use this in several places, just wrap that in a function definition of course:

```
def find_song_by_keyword(user_input):
    return next((song for song, words in keywords.items() if user_input in words), None)


result = find_song_by_keyword('love')
```

Solutions like inverting the dictionary can be a good idea if you have to do this very frequently, since you're trading space for better performance, but of course the action of inverting takes some time as well, so it doesn't appear to match your use case very well.

User @Barmar does make a good point that the original dictionary could be created as a dictionary of 'search term -> file name' instead of the current 'file name -> search term'. You could likely construct a dictionary with search terms as keys about as possibly as you construct the current dictionary, depending on how you plan to construct it.

Comment: You only have to invert the dictionary once when it's created, not every time you search.

Comment: Of course, but you have to invert the entire dictionary and then access the inverted dictionary for each search, which is a more costly operation than searching the original a few times. (apart from potential loss of some information, but that's well beyond the OP's question)

Comment: The dictionary should be created and updated in the inverted mode.